# Xamarin forms & Azure cognitive services : Speech to text service does not work

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-cognitive-services

I am learning Xamarin and I would like to implement the speech to text cognitive service using this url:

I have an error at the line :

```
// Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
            // Replace with your own subscription key // and service region (e.g., "westus").
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("YourSubscriptionKey", "YourServiceRegion");
```

error : `System.DllNotFoundException: Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll`

Thanks

Comment: Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech is a Windows 10 only package (as it supplies native code) as it does not support Xamarin.iOS|Android based devices for continuous speech. If you do not need that feature, you can use the REST APIs.

Comment: @SushiHangover  do you have an example of Rest Apis please

Comment: REST DOCS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/overview#reference-docs and Endpoint/Swagger ref: https://westus.cris.ai/swagger/ui/index

Comment: thanks a  lot  @SushiHangover

Comment: @atomi, about cognitive service, I find one sample that you can take a look:https://github.com/NateRickard/Xamarin.Cognitive.Speech

Answer (score 1):

You need to install that library:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech/

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech -Version 1.6.0
```